# using threads in custom View in android

Tags: android

I have a custom view extending android.view.View in wich am drawing some pictures and moving them  inside the view(from some place to another on the same screen) but i want the user to be able to start that moving from a button and i want a period of 1 seconde to be between each move (picture1 moves and we wait 1 seconde and picture2 moves....) 
so i have had a look on Google and specially (developper.android.com) but things are not yet clear to me : threading inside that class and method invalidate'rol..

so i will be very grateful for anyone who would show me a clear way to do that

Comment: What exactly is it your asking us to help you with?

Comment: I have two lists of images on the view : one in the right and the other in the left. and i have a method which moves images from left list to right list. but i like to move them (from left to right) one by one with 1 second between every two moves but i do not know how so am asking on how to do that.